Problem with the mask in the MaskedTextBox field
I have a problem in winforms with the MaskedTextBox components.
When I open a form the mask is loaded correctly, but if I don't fill it in and close it, when I reopen it the mask disappears. I've searched but haven't found anything that helps.
Has anyone experienced this and knows how to resolve it?
Before
After
I need the mask to stay independent of how many times the form is opened.

set the property of HidePromptOnLeave true
maskedTextBox1.HidePromptOnLeave = true;

It is seem to trigger a redraw of the prompts on focus if it is set to true.
Two work around i can think of.
One on the form show event, loop through all the maskedTextbox if the value is empty string set it some thing then back to empty string.
Second option, on form colse set the hidePromptOnLeave value true and then on form show event set it to false.

This function is to show the mask only when it is in focus. Even so, when I open and close the unformatting behavior, the fields continue and I need the mask to always be visible.
